# Creating a Jmeter test plan automatically without the GUI using curl commands

Tags: curl, jmeter

I'm trying to create a jmeter test plan without using the GUI.
I want to take a file with multiple curl commands in order to create the test plan requests.
The base test configuration can be made with the GUI, but the addition of the requests via the curl commands should be done by a script.
I know there is a way to import those commands into jmeter through the GUI but I need that the test will be created automatically without manual interference.
what could be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with manually starting the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it's not needed you can just [configure cURL to use JMeter as the proxy](https://oxylabs.io/blog/curl-with-proxy). Like:

```
curl -x http://localhost 8888 -k -your-other-parameters https://your-url
```

The sequence of commands can be put into a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).

More information: [Recording a user session with the proxy](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy)